# How to determine how many parts make up a whole number

Tags: vb.net, numbers, match

Apologies for the wording of the title, but sure how else to word it.

The code will possibly speak more than a description. I have knocked up this pseudo code to try and convey what I am trying to achieve. From the example below I would want "Test1" and "test2" to output, but not "test3" or "test4"

```
Dim DEBUG_LOGLEVEL_ALWAYSLOG As Integer = 0
Dim DEBUG_LOGLEVEL_INFORMATIONAL As Integer = 2
Dim DEBUG_LOGLEVEL_HIGHLEVEL As Integer = 4
Dim DEBUG_LOGLEVEL_MIDLEVEL As Integer = 8
Dim DEBUG_LOGLEVEL_LOWLEVEL As Integer = 16
Dim DEBUG_LOGLEVEL_SUBROUTINE As Integer = 32
Dim DEBUG_LOGLEVEL_FUNCTIONHIGHLEVEL As Integer= 64
Dim DEBUG_LOGLEVEL_FUNCTIONLOWLEVEL As Integer= 128

Dim DEBUG_LOGGING_LEVEL As Integer = DEBUG_LOGLEVEL_INFORMATIONAL+DEBUG_LOGLEVEL_HIGHLEVEL+DEBUG_LOGLEVEL_SUBROUTINE+DEBUG_LOGLEVEL_FUNCTIONHIGHLEVEL

Debug_AddLogEntry("Test1", DEBUG_LOGLEVEL_INFORMATIONAL)
Debug_AddLogEntry("Test2", DEBUG_LOGLEVEL_HIGHLEVEL)
Debug_AddLogEntry("Test3", DEBUG_LOGLEVEL_MIDLEVEL)
Debug_AddLogEntry("Test4", DEBUG_LOGLEVEL_SUBROUTINE)


Function Debug_AddLogEntry(text, loglevel)
    IF loglevel is contained within DEBUG_LOGGING_LEVEL
    'Code
Endif
End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pretty close. First, you'll want everything as a power of 2. You almost have that, just change your first line. 0 is not a power of 2, but 1 is:

```
Dim DEBUG_LOGLEVEL_ALWAYSLOG As Integer = 1
```

Then, for your debug function, you can use a bitwise operation to check.

```
Function Debug_AddLogEntry(text, loglevel)
    IF (loglevel And DEBUG_LOGGING_LEVEL) = loglevel
```

That will only return true if that bit is set to one.

Furthermore, you can change your initial definitions to be more clear (and easier to add upon) by using bitwise shifts. For instance:

```
Dim DEBUG_LOGLEVEL_ALWAYSLOG As Integer = 1 << 0
Dim DEBUG_LOGLEVEL_INFORMATIONAL As Integer = 1 << 1
Dim DEBUG_LOGLEVEL_HIGHLEVEL As Integer = 1 << 2
Dim DEBUG_LOGLEVEL_MIDLEVEL As Integer = 1 << 3
...
etc
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for all the answers guys! First time posting here, so very impressed :) I originally had DEBUG_LOGLEVEL_ALWAYSLOG=1 but then changed it to 0, doh! I shall give it a try tommorrow as it's been a long day and need sleep.